# regsvr32 registration procedure failed на Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dll

запускаю

```
 regsvr32.exe ./Builder.dll
```

Получаю на Linux:

```
 dll can't be registered (registration procedure failed) 
 make: *** Error 1
```

Builder.dll - модуль, необходимый мне для запуска тестов, до него были собраны и зарегистрированы 2 других модуля, все получилось.

dll надо собрать под linux, исходный код лежит на linux-сервере. доступ к серверу, на котором собираю, по ssh, запускаю сборку dll в консоли посредством `make`. Собственно, `dll can't be registered (registration procedure failed)` - это все, что получаю в консоли, без каких-либо пояснений, кодов и т.д. Будем считать, что исходников нет, т.е. не могу выложить, это проект, который вяло кочует с Win на linux, проект не мой, честно.

Как узнать зависимости dll для регистрации?

Comment: Что такое `Builder.dll`, и что вы пытаетесь получить?

Comment: Перенес с меты. Подправьте заголовок и метки по вкусу.

Comment: я не понял, причем тут linux. Где ты запускаешь эту команду?

Comment: Вопрос надо задавать ПОНЯТНО, тогда его не будут минусовать и пытаться закрыть. Приводить понятные текстовки, приводить исходники кода, коды ошибок и т.п. (Смотрите в справке "как задавать хорошие вопросы") Вы вот не написали, как вы запускали на linux этот код (штатно dll от видны не подходят для Linux, аналогично elf на винде не запустить -- и это [легко гуглится](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/352823)), не написали. А мы не телепаты. Хорошо заданный вопрос -- половина ответа и это ВАША работа, как спрашивающего.

Comment: @JohnDoe, а кто автор этой библиотеки dll, есть её исходный код?

Comment: Как отследить зависимости - http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: dll надо собрать для linux, исходный код лежит на linux-сервере. доступ к серверу, на котором собираю, по ssh, запускаю сборку dll в консоли посредством `make`. Собственно, `dll can't be registered (registration procedure failed)` - это все, что получаю в консоли, без каких-либо пояснений, кодов и т.д. Будем считать, что исходников нет, т.е. не могу выложить, это проект, который вяло кочует с Win на linux, проект не мой, честно. Намекаете на точку входа для regsvr32? По поводу dependencywalker - его из консоли запустить можно?

Comment: Всю полезную информацию вносите в вопрос, в комментариях при этом можно упомянуть участника, чтобы он получил уведомление и увидел отредактированный вопрос. Добавьте к вопросу подходящие метки, в частности, язык, на котором написана библиотека.

Comment: @A K есть что-нибудь похожее (dependencywalker) для linux?